# Configuration of something VS Something configuration

Tags: meaning

In a to-do list, i would write that i have to configure a operating system. What's the difference in this case (if any) between "operating system configuration" and "configuration of operating system"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may mean the same thing or they may not.

One way that they don't mean the same thing is as follows.

> "That operating system configuration is all wrong."

Here, I'm describing a thing. All activity has ceased and there is a final result.

> "Your configuration of that operating system won't work out the way you want. Stop and start over."

Here, I'm telling somebody who's in the process of configuring the operating system that they're doing it wrong. The subject is there activity, not a final result.

---

Context will determine meaning. It's also possible that the other phrasing could have been used in each scenario. But I think it's likely that the first would more often describe a final state (where *configuration* is used as part of a noun phrase) while the second would more often describe a process (where *configuration* is used as verbal description).

It's certainly the case that if you're talking about a to-do list with an entry reading *have to configure an operating system*, *configure* is a verb and not a noun.